# how is "force" in Indian law interpreted based on section 349 of the Indian penal code?

Tags: legal-terms, definition, indian-penal-code

Indian penal code defines "force" as

> A person is said to use force to another if he causes motion, change of motion, or cessation of motion to that other, or if he causes to any substance such motion, or change of motion, or cessation of motion as brings that substance into contact with any part of that other’s body, or with anything which that other is wearing or carrying, or with anything so situated that such contact affects that other’s sense of feeling;
>
> Provided that the person causing the motion, or change of motion, or cessation of motion, causes that motion, change of motion, or cessation of motion in one of the three ways hereinafter described:
>
> - By his own bodily power.
> - By disposing any substance in such a manner that the motion or change or cessation of motion takes place without any further act on his part, or on the part of any other person.
> - By inducing any animal to move, to change its motion, or to cease to move

this has been used in crimes involving force or crimes which have the term "physical contact"
how broadly is this interpreted by courts ? the way it is worded it seems like it implies even things that don't involve touching by own body or by another substance are included like media and electronic communications(like messages and calling) as long as it invokes a "feeling"

a case law regarding this is

https://indiankanoon.org/doc/123392914/

which involves sexual abuse of a child. the judgement states that physical contact Includes cases where the victim isn't touched as well. is this really how it is interpreted ?

update;; as a seperate question. the judgement I linked also includes a statement by the supreme court that courts can't interpret laws in a way to destroys their object or purpose. are there any exceptions to this and wouldn't this be judicial overreach ? isn't it the job of legislatures to draft consistent and clear laws ?

Comment: did you also ask https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89215/what-does-the-term-makes-her-to-do-so-with-him-or-any-other-person-mean-in-ipc ? You might want to create an account and combine the logins.

Comment: yes I forgot j logged in as a guest my bad

Comment: That's a different question. You should register your account and contact staff to combine them, which will result in your questions both being owned by your proper account.

Comment: Please request merger of your two accounts through the community team [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact). Under "Contact Support" you select "Account issue" --> "I need to merge user profiles"